# how to get the keys sorted by custom comparator in map-reduce job in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, comparator, hadoop2

Consider this `class`: (From `Hadoop: The definitive guide` 3rd edition):

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

public class TextPair implements WritableComparable<TextPair> {

  private Text first;
  private Text second;

  public TextPair() {
    set(new Text(), new Text());
  }

  public TextPair(String first, String second) {
    set(new Text(first), new Text(second));
  }

  public TextPair(Text first, Text second) {
    set(first, second);
  }

  public void set(Text first, Text second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }

  public Text getFirst() {
    return first;
  }

  public Text getSecond() {
    return second;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    first.write(out);
    second.write(out);
  }

  @Override
  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    first.readFields(in);
    second.readFields(in);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return first.hashCode() * 163 + second.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof TextPair) {
      TextPair tp = (TextPair) o;
      return first.equals(tp.first) && second.equals(tp.second);
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return first + "\t" + second;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(TextPair tp) {
    int cmp = first.compareTo(tp.first);
    if (cmp != 0) {
      return cmp;
    }
    return second.compareTo(tp.second);
  }
  // ^^ TextPair

  // vv TextPairComparator
  public static class Comparator extends WritableComparator {

    private static final Text.Comparator TEXT_COMPARATOR = new Text.Comparator();

    public Comparator() {
      super(TextPair.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1,
                       byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {

      try {
        int firstL1 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]) + readVInt(b1, s1);
        int firstL2 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[s2]) + readVInt(b2, s2);
        int cmp = TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1, firstL1, b2, s2, firstL2);
        if (cmp != 0) {
          return cmp;
        }
        return TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1 + firstL1, l1 - firstL1,
                                       b2, s2 + firstL2, l2 - firstL2);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  static {
    WritableComparator.define(TextPair.class, new Comparator());
  }
  // ^^ TextPairComparator

  // vv TextPairFirstComparator
  public static class FirstComparator extends WritableComparator {

    private static final Text.Comparator TEXT_COMPARATOR = new Text.Comparator();

    public FirstComparator() {
      super(TextPair.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1,
                       byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {

      try {
        int firstL1 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]) + readVInt(b1, s1);
        int firstL2 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[s2]) + readVInt(b2, s2);
        return TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1, firstL1, b2, s2, firstL2);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
      if (a instanceof TextPair && b instanceof TextPair) {
        return ((TextPair) a).first.compareTo(((TextPair) b).first);
      }
      return super.compare(a, b);
    }
  }
  // ^^ TextPairFirstComparator

// vv TextPair
}
// ^^ TextPair
```

There are two kinds of `comparators` defined:
one is sorting by `first` followed by `second` which is the default `comparator.`
The other is sorting by `first` ONLY, which is the `firstComparator.`

If I have to use use firstComparator for sorting my keys, how do I achieve that?
That is, how do I override my default comparator with the `first comparator`, I defined above.

Secondly, how would I `unitTest` this since the output of `map` job is not `sorted`. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have to use use firstComparator for sorting my keys, how do I achieve that? That is, how do I override my default comparator with the first comparator, I defined above.

I assume you expect a method something like setComparator(firstComparator). As far as I know there is no such method. The keys are sorted (on the mapper side) using the `compareTo()` of the `Writeable` type representing the keys. In your case, the `compareTo()` method checks the first value and then the second one. In other words, the keys will be sorted by the first value and, then, the keys in the same group (i.e. having the same first value) will be sorted by their second value.

All in all, this means that your keys will always be sorted by the first value (+ by the second value if the first one isn't able to take the decision). Which in turn means that there is no need to have a different comparator (`firstComparator`) which looks only at the first value because that is already achieved with the `compareTo()` method of your `TextPair` class.

On the other hand, if the `firstComparator` sorts the keys completely differently, the only solution is to move the logic in `firstComparator` to the `compareTo()` method of the `Writable` class representing your key. I don't see any reason why you wouldn't do that. If you already have the `firstComparator` and want to reuse it, you can instantiate it and invoke it in the `compareTo()` method of the `TexPair` `Writable`.

You might also want to take a look at the `GroupingComparator` which is used to decide which keys are used  together in the same call of the `reduce()` method. Since you didn't describe exactly what you want to achieve, I can't say for sure if this will be helpful or not.

> Secondly, how would I unitTest this since the output of map job is not sorted. ?

Unit testing, as the name says, implies testing a single unit of code (most of the time a method/function/procedure). If you want to unit-test your reduce method **you** have to provide the interesting input cases and to check that the method under test outputs the expected result. More concretely, you have to create/mock a sorted Iterable over your keys and invoke your reduce function with it. Unit testing a reduce method shouldn't rely on the execution of the corresponding map method.

Comment: That was just an example. lets say my firstcomparator actually sorts for the second value and if they are same, it will sort on first value (which is reverse of my compareTo). how do you achieve that? and btw, is the output of mapper is always sorted. That is if you print the context object, do you see the keys sorted always. I don't think so

Comment: the partitioned output of the mapping phase is sorted by key before being passed to the reducer. I updated my answer.

Comment: and how can I persist the partitioned output of the mapping phase to have a look at it physically. That is how can I see partitioned output to check for its correctness..

Comment: in the conf/mapred-site.xml configuration file on the tasktracker on which the map task whose output your looking for ran, you should find this property: mapreduce.cluster.local.dir. In case you don't find it you should look at this location: ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local where hadoop.tmp.dir is defined in the core-default.xml configuration file